# Fail to submit a form in yii

Tags: yii

i am having a page with grid view and some checkbox fields init.

i added a submit button to it by adding echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit-form');

But, that button is not responding.

why so?

how i should submit this form?

[my view page](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=qEdSKrpU)

[my controller page](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=mN4uTiDB)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have:

```
public function actionmyaction()
{
    echo \'myaction reaced\';

    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

You have to use camelcase with that, so actionMyaction() would probably do the trick.

Comment: submit button is not at all redirecting to this action. it's just not responding.

Comment: You can use `CHtml:ajaxSubmitButton` instead or `echo CHtml::button('Submit',array('onclick'=>'submit()'));`

Comment: And `CHtml::button('Submit',array('onclick'=>'submit()'));`?